# Assigning string to char array vs. struct function

Tags: c++, arrays

Okay so I know that the following doesn't work. I can't declare a char array, and then assign it later as follows.

```
char a[20]; 
a = "Hello World"; //SYNTAX ERROR

cout << a;
```

However, when I use a struct data type, it seems like I can assign a char array after it's been initialized.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Student 
{
    char name[10]; 
}

int main()
{
   Student student1; 
   student1 = {"Will"};

   cout << student1.name; 
}
```

This prints out:
Will

Why does this work?

Comment: The codes are not equivalent. `student1.name = "Will";` still does not work.

Comment: Works in vscode, but it didn't work in another compiler

Comment: @eotsso works fine in gcc: https://godbolt.org/z/o9MWeqEzY

Comment: Note that `”Hello World”`is an array of twelve characters. It won’t fit in `char a[10];`. That’s not the reason for the error; it’s the next problem you’ll run into when you try to use `strcpy`.

Comment: @pete becker thank you I fixed it in my original post. It was only meant to be a quick example

Answer (score 2):

The 2nd code works because a temporary is being initialized by [Aggregate Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), and then that temporary is assigned to `student1`, which copies each member's value.

Answer (score 0):

A simple struct like you have has aggregate initialization and is trivially copyable. So when you write

```
student1 = {"Will"};
```

a temporary object `Student` is created via aggregate initialization and then the copy assignment operator is called.

But what you should be using is `std::string`.